# Express.js mounted applications - Handlebars layout and partial inheritance?

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

I've got two Express.js apps, `main` and `sub`, which use `express-hbs` for their view engine.

I am attempting to make `sub` into its own standalone module with its own set of layouts, partials, and views. Running it independently produces the behavior I expect: it renders its own layouts, partials, and views.

In my case, I intend to make `main` into a utility with some additional features. `main` has its own set of layouts, partials, and views. `sub` is to be mounted on `main`.

Once mounted on `main` and after `main` is started, `main` renders its own layouts, partials, and views correctly. However, while `sub`'s views are rendered appropriately, `sub` seems to inherit `main`'s layouts and partials instead of using its own, which is not what I intended.

What am I missing, here? Why does `sub` appear to inherit `main`'s layouts and partials, but not `main`'s views?

I've taken my use case and made a simple example out of it.

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var hbs = require('express-hbs');
var path = require('path');
var sub = require('sub');

var main = express();

var handlebars = hbs.express4({
  beautify:      true,
  defaultLayout: path.join(__dirname, './views/layouts/default'),
  partialsDir:   path.join(__dirname, './views/partials'),
  layoutsDir:    path.join(__dirname, './views/layouts')
});

// Set the application's view engine.
main.engine('hbs', handlebars);
main.set('view engine', 'hbs');
main.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './views'));

main.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

main.use('/sub', sub);

// Different (correct) directories, but only rendering main's layouts and partials.
console.log('main', main.get('views'));
console.log('sub', sub.get('views'));


main.listen(3000);
```

**sub/index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var hbs = require('express-hbs');
var path = require('path');

var sub = express();

var handlebars = hbs.express4({
  beautify:      true,
  defaultLayout: path.join(__dirname, './views/default/layouts/default'),
  partialsDir:   path.join(__dirname, './views/default/partials'),
  layoutsDir:    path.join(__dirname, './views/default/layouts')
});

sub.engine('hbs', handlebars);
sub.set('view engine', 'hbs');
sub.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './views/default'));

sub.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

module.exports = sub;
```

A more complete example is [available here.](https://github.com/ConnorWiseman/express-hbs-layouts-quirks)

Is there a way to keep view directories separate between mounted Express.js applications?

**Edit 1:** weird layout inheritance behavior persists, even when defining specific layouts to use in any of `sub`'s routes. They're just ignored, entirely, by `sub` when it's mounted on `main`.

**Edit 2:** odd behavior persists in [exphbs](https://github.com/gnowoel/exphbs), [express-hbs](https://github.com/barc/express-hbs), and [express-handlebars](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars). Is what I'm experiencing peculiar to express itself?

**Edit 3:** I may be able to leverage [something like this](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars/issues/181) to work around what I'm experiencing, but I'd still like to know why mounted apps won't render their own layouts and partials, if anyone has any ideas. It'd be much more convenient for me!